# Blazor Server Authentication, PostgreSQL, and Keycloak integrations

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm currently trying to integrate an existing Blazor Server (ASP.NET Core 6.0, server-side only) application with my company's Keycloak authentication services. I need to use the existing .NET Authentication/Authorization libraries with the Keycloak - the Keycloak will hold all the relevant User data I need to access (e.g. ID, name, passwords, etc.) and use that data as query parameters to access the data stored in PostgreSQL. I've seen that this is possible with Microsoft SQL Server, so I'm wondering if the following is even possible:

- Using something other than Microsoft SQL Server or SQLite to handle Authentication with .NET
- Using a remote server database to handle Authentication instead of a local .db migration
- Accessing Keycloak data for authentication instead of data stored in said local .db migration
- If all of this is possible on Blazor Server instead of WebAssembly

There's tons of documentation on how to use SQL Server in a WebAssembly for authentication, but what little documentation exists for Blazor Server, and Keycloak, is for older .NET versions (usually 2.0) and very, very basic use cases. There's also questions already asked but haven't been answered. I'm still very new to Web development and Blazor, so if this isn't even possible, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Have a look at my authentication template example https://github.com/iso8859/AspNetCoreAuthMultiLang